# How to install facebook watchman on ubuntu?

Tags: python, facebook, react-native, watchman

I got watchman from github link https://github.com/facebook/watchman.git, then I got watchman folder and tried this

```
./autogen.sh 

./autogen.sh: 9: ./autogen.sh: aclocal: not found

./autogen.sh: 10: ./autogen.sh: autoheader: not found

./autogen.sh: 11: ./autogen.sh: automake: not found

./autogen.sh: 12: ./autogen.sh: autoconf: not found
```

Why ? I have `python 2.7.9`.

Could it be the cause ? ( I use `ubuntu 15.04` btw)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need to install each of the missing packages.

For example on ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install automake  <=== contains autoheader, ...
$ sudo apt-get install autoconf
```

If you wind up with a bunch of errors like AC_* undefined, then you may need a more up-to-date version of automake.  You can download the source from the gnu repo ... see:  https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/

Answer (score 4):

If getting following error  on `$ ./autogen.sh`

```
$ ./autogen.sh
./autogen.sh: 9: ./autogen.sh: aclocal: not found
./autogen.sh: 10: ./autogen.sh: autoheader: not found
./autogen.sh: 11: ./autogen.sh: automake: not found
./autogen.sh: 12: ./autogen.sh: autoconf: not found
```

You’ll need to install automake && autoconf.

As i did the following:

```
sudo apt-get install automake autoconf
```

Then proceed with the steps for `./autogen.sh`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

With Watchman v4.9.0 on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y autoconf automake build-essential python-dev libtool pkg-config libssl-dev
```

Then follow the instructions as per https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html#installing-from-source :

```
git clone https://github.com/facebook/watchman.git
cd watchman
git checkout v4.9.0  # the latest stable release
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 0):

1. List item

$ cd ~
$ git clone https://github.com/facebook/watchman.git
$ cd watchman/
$ git checkout v4.7.0
$ sudo apt-get install -y autoconf automake build-essential python-dev
$ ./autogen.sh 
$ ./configure 
$ make
$ sudo make install

$ watchman --version
$ echo 999999 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches  && echo 999999 | sudo tee -a  /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_queued_events && echo 999999 | sudo tee  -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances && watchman  shutdown-server